# combine two files line after line using cat

Tags: shell, unix, cat

I have two files: F1, F2 as

*F1*

```
f1row1  
f1row2  
..
```

*F2*

```
f2row1  
f2row2  
..
```

using

```
cat F1 F2 > F3
```

gives

```
f1row1  
f1row2  
..  
<end of file1>
f2row1  
f2row2  
..  
<end of file2>
```

I would like to create a third file as:

*F3*

```
f1row1  
f2row1  
f1row2  
f2row2  
..
```

Any suggestions to do this using *cat* command? I searched for similar questions but didn't find one.

Much thanks.

Comment: Are `..`s literal lines?

Comment: no, just that there are several lines. Thank you for editing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your input files contain the same number of records

```
paste -d '\n' F1 F2
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a script for Bash. It could work with multiple files (within max opened files limit) not just 2 and could work with variable length of lines.

```
#!/bin/bash

I=3
for F; do
    eval "exec $I< \"\$F\""
    (( ++I ))
done

for (( ;; )); do
    LINES=()
    for (( J = 3; J < I; ++J )); do
        IFS= read -ru "$J" && LINES+=("$REPLY")
    done
    [[ ${#LINES[@]} -eq 0 ]] && break
    printf '%s\n' "${LINES[@]}"
done
```

Usage:

```
bash script.sh file1 file2 ...
```

Test:

```
bash script.sh <(seq 1 2) <(seq 1 3) <(seq 1 4)
```

Output:

```
1
1
1
2
2
2
3
3
4
```

And so I'm tempted to compare results with `paste`:

```
paste -d '\n' <(seq 1 2) <(seq 1 3)
```

Output:

```
1
1
2
2

3
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. the one liner by @1_CR did the job for me :D

Comment: this solution also covers variable line length, will be useful for me in the future.